# Django REST framework - require BooleanField to be true

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework, boolean

Hi I'm trying to create a rest api with Django REST framework with a boolean field to be required to be true.

Inside the model I have:

```
class MyForm(models.Model):
    ...
    agree_terms = models.BooleanField()
```

and in my serializer I have:

```
class MyFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyForm
        fields = (..., 'agree_terms')
```

The problem is that I can POST to this api `agree_terms = false` and I'm trying to make it required to be `True`.

I've tried adding to the serializer:

```
accept_terms = fields.BooleanField(required=True)
```

but it didn't worked for me.

Is there is a way to make it work?

Thanks in advance,

Etay.

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `validate()`. Setting `required=True` makes the field a required field, meaning that it has to be present in the post body no matter its value.

```
class MyFormSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyForm
        fields = (..., 'agree_terms')
    def validate_agree_terms(self, value):
        if not value:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("Validation error")
        return value
```

[docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation)

Answer (score 2):

you can validate like this

```
def validate_accept_terms(self, value):
    if value is not True:
        raise serializers.ValidationError("terms must be accepted")
    return value
```

and put this function in your serializer